# UITableView returning nil when trying to call reloadData()

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to get my table view to show json data from the news api. I've been able to parse the data and display it to the console but a nil value was caught in the self.tableview.reload(). I need help in resolving the issue

```
let urlRequest = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everythingq=Coronavirus&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey"
   var articles: [Articles]? = []
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        retriveData()
 
      }
    
    func retriveData(){
       guard let aritcleUrl = URL(string: urlRequest) else {
                  return
              }
              
              let request = URLRequest(url: aritcleUrl)
              let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                  
                if  error != nil {
                    print(error ?? 0)
                      return
                  }
                  if let data = data {
                      self.articles = self.parseData(data: data)
                      
                      // Reload table view
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableview.reloadData()
                    }
                       
                  }
                   
                 
              })
              
              task.resume()
    }
    
    
    func parseData(data:Data)-> [Articles]   {
     var articles: [Articles]? = []

        do {
            let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            
            let jsonArticles = jsonResult?["articles"] as? [AnyObject] ?? []
          
            for jsonArticle in jsonArticles{
                let article = Articles()
                article.author = jsonArticle["author"] as? String
                article.title = jsonArticle["title"] as? String
                article.publishedAt = jsonArticle["publishedAt"] as? String
                articles?.append(article)
            }
           
            print(jsonArticles)

         } catch {
            print(error)
        }
         
        return articles ??  []
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your class doesn't conform to table view's protocols.
You should edit your declaration to:

```
class <YourViewController>: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
```

then in the viewDidLoad you should set the delegate and datasource to your tableview

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    
    retriveData()
  }
```

Then you have to add the protocol stubs as suggested by xcode

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        self.articles?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // YOUR CELL CUSTOMIZATION GOES HERE
    }
```

However I suggest you to look at any TableView tutorial on Internet, such as the Apple's official one
[here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html)